# unselected gridview items?

Tags: android, gridview

i have a game project that has a problem.in my game has a grid with 20 item. user should selected multi item that == main Number (6+2+4+8 == 20)

### [image: screen of my game: Grid items]

when click on items that it's position above 9 (two digits), both itself and the first item is selected. for exam: for item by position 14: item 14 & item 1 is selected when click on item 14.

it's my java code:
1. grid.onItemClickListener :

```
if(Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(position)+"")+sum_main < Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString())){
            // define action when: sum_main < Number
            sum_main  += Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(position)+"");
            String sm = position+"";
            if(sm.length() > 1){
                Log.d("11","Ok");
                sbVars.append(slash);
                sbVars.append(string.charAt(position));
                sbPoss.append(slash);
                sbPoss.append(position);
                Log.d("12","Ok");
            }else{ Log.d("13","Ok");
                sbVars.append(string.charAt(position));
                sbPoss.append(position); Log.d("14","Ok");
            }
            view.setEnabled(false);
            Log.d("15","Ok");
            n = 1;
            Toast.makeText(MplusN_Game.this, sbPoss+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else if(Integer.parseInt(string.charAt(position)+"")+sum_main == Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString())){
            // define action when: sum_main = Number
            sum_main = 0;
            String sm = position+"";
            if(sm.length() > 1){
                sbVars.append("/");
                sbVars.append(string.charAt(position));
                sbPoss.append("/");
                sbPoss.append(position);
            }else{
                sbVars.append(string.charAt(position));
                sbPoss.append(position);
            }
            tv.setText(setNumber()+"");
            n = 2;
            deleteVarsOfString();
        }else{
            // define action when: sum_main > Number
            sum_main = 0;
            n = 3;
        }
        setStatesGridItems(n);// method for change bg of selected items
        }
    });
```

2. this is setStateGridItems() method

   `for(int i=0; i<sbPoss.length(); i++){
                   String s = sbPoss.charAt(i)+"";
                   if(s.equals(slash)){
                       String ss = sbPoss.charAt(i+1)+""+sbPoss.charAt(i+2);
                       int t1 = Integer.parseInt(ss);
                       grid.getChildAt(t1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_grid_items_bloo100);
                       Log.w("1","OK");
                   }
                   else{
                       Log.w("2","OK");
                       if(i > 1){
                           Log.w("21","OK");
                           String s2 = sbPoss.charAt(i-1)+"";
                           String s3 = sbPoss.charAt(i-2)+"";
                           if(s2.equals(slash))
                               if(s3.equals(slash)){
                                   Log.w("211","OK");
                                   continue;
                               }
                           else{
                               int t = Integer.parseInt(sbPoss.charAt(i)+"");
                               grid.getChildAt(t).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_grid_items_bloo100);
                               grid.getChildAt(t).setEnabled(false);
                                   Log.w("212","OK");
                           }
                       }else{
                           Log.w("22","OK");
                           if(i==0){
                               int t = Integer.parseInt(sbPoss.charAt(0)+"");
                               grid.getChildAt(t).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_grid_items_bloo100);
                               grid.getChildAt(t).setEnabled(false);
                               Log.w("221","OK");
                           }else{
                               Log.w("222","OK");
                               String s2 = sbPoss.charAt(i-1)+"";
                               if(s2.equals(slash)){
                                   Log.w("2221","OK");
                                   continue;
                               }
                               else{
                                   Log.w("2222","OK");
                                   int t = Integer.parseInt(sbPoss.charAt(i)+"");
                                   grid.getChildAt(t).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_grid_items_bloo100);
                                   grid.getChildAt(t).setEnabled(false);
                               }
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }`

**please solve this problem.thank you**